# solidity - Smart contract - function pass parameter

Tags: function, parameters, solidity, contract

I'm having problems setting a value in a deployed BSC smart contract, below is the problematic solidity function, is the fact '_value' has been used not 'value' as the pass parameter ?

```
function setSwapTokensAtAmount(uint256 _value) external onlyOwner
{
    swapTokensAtAmount = _value;
}
```

I have looked at other contracts and can't see any that use the '_' when labelling a pass parameter value, which can be used (from my understanding) denote a public or private variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice to name function-scoped variables starting with underscore. But naming the variable with or without underscore doesn't have any effect on the resulting functionality.

I see that your function uses the `onlyOwner` modifier. While your code doesn't show the modifier implementation, we can assume that it controls that only authorized sender can execute the function.

So a very likely reason why you cannot update the variable is that you're trying to execute the function from a different address than the authorized `owner`.

Comment: Thanks, other functions also use the onlyOwner modifier and they work OK.. for some reason the 'swapTokensAtAmount' which had an initial value assigned is returning maximum unit256 value (5789....), but unable to change it, and this function is the only place it can be changed

Comment: @Leeboy22001 Based on the function name `swapTokensAtAmount`, I'm assuming it makes a call to an external contract where some other validations might occur. So it's likely a logical error - e.g. you're passing values that fail validations in the other contract.